# Powershell copy directories using a csv listing

Tags: powershell, csv, get-childitem, import-csv

Hey I am fairly new to PowerShell and I am trying to create a movie transfer script. I have create a script that will list the child-items from my movie folder and dump them to a .csv. The end user will then be able to select files within the .csv and place a 'y' in another column. I will then run a Powershell script to filter out their selection using the 'y' column and compare and copy-items to a separate folder/drive.

I am having some issues with comparing the .csv with the original folder where the movies are kept and then copying them over to another folder. My script will only find and copy one array item at a time using [0] etc.

Here is an example of my export-csv script (which works without issue) and my copy-item script (which has the issues)

**EXPORT-CSV.ps1**

```
$Movies = "D:\Media\Movies"

Get-ChildItem $Movies | select name,y | Export-Csv D:\Media\Media_Scripts\Movies.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

And an Image of the output .csv file

[Movies.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvGfY.png)

**COPY-ITEM.ps1** Works but only when i add a single array number in [] after $csv_name. This is not ideal because I would like to recurse and copy all the selected folders to the new location

```
$Csv_loc = "D:\Media\Media_Scripts\"
$Movies_loc = "D:\Media\Movies\"
$Test = "D:\Media\Media_Scripts\Test\"

$csv = Import-Csv "$csv_loc\Movies.csv" | Where-Object{$_.y -eq "y"} | select name

$csv_name | foreach($_)
{ 
Get-ChildItem $movies_loc | Where-Object {$_.Name -contains $csv_name[0]} | copy-item -Destination $Test -Recurse -Verbose
}
```

Comment: `$csv_name` is empty. You never assign anything to it. Also you create a path with double backslashes. You can avoid mistakes like that by using `Join-Path`. And you use foreach wrong.

Comment: Thanks mate, and sorry I wrote my variable wrong (it was meant to be just $csv)

Comment: You need to edit your question to reflect the corrections that Swonkie pointed out.  Also your foreach($_) is very unclear to me.  Are you trying for the construct that's often written with a percent sign?

Answer (score 0):

I think it seems that you are getting an array and can't resolve the name to be copied.

```
$MoviesPath = "C:\Setup\Movies"

Get-ChildItem C:\setup\Movies | select Name, Available | Export-Csv C:\Setup\Movies.csv -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I made some changes on the delimiter as I don't use the default ones.

```
$Csv_location = "C:\Setup\"
$Movies_location = "C:\Setup\Movies"
$DestinationPath = "C:\Setup\"

$Tempcsv = Import-Csv "C:\Setup\Movies.csv" -Delimiter "|" -Encoding UTF8 | Where-Object {$_.Available -eq "y"} | Select Name

foreach ($Movie in $Tempcsv) {
    $Tempname = $Movie.name
    Copy-Item -Path $Movies_location\$Tempname -Destination $DestinationPath -Recurse -Verbose }
```

If I put in a $tempname the $movie.name I can copy all the files but without that I get as a name the @{moviename} in the file path that does not exist.

You can use this as a workaround for the moment. I will come back with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for the help guys. I apologise for not being too clear in my question, thanks for taking the time to have a look at for me. I got some clarification through an external source and the script to accomplish what I was trying to achieve is this;

```
$movies_loc = gci "D:\Media\Movies" -Recurse
$Dest = "D:\Media\Media_Scripts\Test"

$csv_name = import-csv "D:\Media\Media_Scripts\Movies.csv" | ? {$_.y -eq "y"} | Select -ExpandProperty name

foreach($csv_n in $csv_name){

    foreach ($movie_loc in $movies_loc){

    if("$movie_loc" -contains "$csv_n"){

    Copy-Item -Path "D:\Media\Movies\$movie_loc" -Destination $Dest -Recurse -Verbose

    }
  }
}
```